# Python YouTube Reporting API Authentication

Tags: python, google-api, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-python-client

I've sorted through many threads on this topic but most seem outdated.

I am trying to call the YouTube Reporting API with [this script](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/code_samples/python?authuser=1)

However I keep getting an error:

- When using 'Desktop Application' OAuth, I get:

> **Error 400: invalid_request**, The out-of-band (OOB) flow has been blocked in order to keep users secure.

- When using 'Web Application' OAuth, I get:

> **Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch**, The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type.

I am just still testing my code and been running out of jupyter notebook and Visual Studio Code. Same errors on both.

I am still a little confused as to which one I should be using, but adding redirect URI's for my localhost is not working, not sure how to proceed.

**EDIT:**
I am using the below code sample directly from YouTube Documentation:

```
import os
import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly']

API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtubeAnalytics'
API_VERSION = 'v2'
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = 'CREDENTIALS.json'
def get_service():
  flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
  credentials = flow.run_console()
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = credentials)

def execute_api_request(client_library_function, **kwargs):
  response = client_library_function(
    **kwargs
  ).execute()

  print(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPs verification when running locally.
  # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled when running in production.
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

  youtubeAnalytics = get_service()
  execute_api_request(
      youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
      ids='channel==MINE',
      startDate='2017-01-01',
      endDate='2017-12-31',
      metrics='estimatedMinutesWatched,views,likes,subscribersGained',
      dimensions='day',
      sort='day'
  )
```

Like mentioned I have http://localhost:8888, http://localhost:8888/oauth2callback etc. In my json file + in Google Console.

'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob' is not in my code/file/google console at any point. I also have the .../auth/yt-analytics.readonly defined in my OAuth consent screen settings.

Really not sure what I have missed out on.

Comment: please edit your question and include your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is meant to be used with 'Desktop Application' type of credentials.

YouTube's documentation is outdated, the below needs to be changed for it to work:

```
credentials = flow.run_console()
```

changed to

```
credentials = flow.run_local_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

> When using 'Desktop Application' OAuth, I get:
> Error 400: invalid_request, The out-of-band (OOB) flow has been blocked in order to keep users secure.

Open your credentials.json file is there a redirect uri that looks like this `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` if so delete it.

> When using 'Web Application' OAuth, I get:
> Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch, The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type.

`urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` is not a valid redirect uri for web or or installed apps anymore. Not that it ever was for web.   You can only use http://localhost for installed apps now.

Comment: The only redirect URI that are inside of the credentials.json file are my redirect URI's which I have wrote before downloading it, this includes both "http://localhost:8888" and "http://127.0.0.1:8888". 

There is no mention of 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob' anywhere

Comment: Make sure you are using web app code if you have created web credentials.  there is a difference

Comment: I have edited the questions and posted the code I am using, it is directly from the YouTube documentation. I have created both web app + desktop app oauth credentials and none seem to work.

Comment: there's your issue docs say to create Install creds as its installed app code InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE

Comment: Although I cannot see any option to create 'installed application' credentials? Only Web App, Desktop App and a bunch of others which don't seem to fit the case?

Comment: desktop is installed app they keep changing the name

Comment: So right back at the 'Error 400: invalid_request, The out-of-band (OOB) flow has been blocked in order to keep users secure' error with localhost URI's in the file...